# FormControl ValueChanges Pipe Not Firing

Tags: angular

I have a need to update the component if the component has an `input` value. While doing so, I am setting values that would normally be set by inserting text into the `input` and selecting list value from an `autocomplete`. Even though I set an `object` to a `FormControl` variable, the `valueChanges`pipe doesn't see it that way. But I'm sure the `formControl` gets the value because on the front-end I show the data by `formControl.value ? formControl.value.Name : ''` and on my case there's a legitimate name in the form control's input.

This is how I show the data;

```
<div class="col-6" *ngIf="departmentUserList.length > 0">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="User" matInput [formControl]="departmentUserControl"
            [matAutocomplete]="userAutoComplete" 
            [value]="departmentUserControl.value ? departmentUserControl.value.Name : ''">
        <mat-autocomplete #userAutoComplete="matAutocomplete"
        (optionSelected)="valueChange('SolvingUser', $event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUserList | async" [value]="user">
                {{user.Name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

This is my `valueChanges` pipe which I put into the `ngOninit`;

```
this.filteredUserList = this.departmentUserControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => {
    console.log("ToFilterValue =>>", value); // this is always '', from the startWith and does not change until I choose from the matAutoComplete
    
    return typeof value === 'string' ? this.filterUser(value) : this.filterUser(value ? value.Name : '')
  })
);
```

This is how I update the value if there's one; (this function is called inside ngOnInit before the declarations of the valueChanges pipes)

```
mapObjects(){
    // does not fire the valuechanges
    this.departmentUserControl.setValue(this.bar.SolvingUser);
}
```

This is a small sample of what my code is;
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rezxtp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 issues.

1. You have to add `subscribe()` to `valueChanges`.
2. You have to call `this.mapObjects()` after `valueChanges`.

```
    this.filteredUserList = this.departmentUserControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      map(value => {
        console.log("ToFilterValue =>>", value);
        return typeof value === "string"
          ? this.filterUser(value)
          : this.filterUser(value ? value.Name : "");
      })
    ).subscribe();
    this.mapObjects();
```

Comment: how did I miss that `mapObjects()` location :D thank you for your help :)